# Angularjs interceptor not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to create a `$http` interceptor that looks like this:

```
.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider){
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q,$window){
    return {
        'request':function(config){
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if($window.sessionStorage)
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer '+$window.sessionStorage.token;
        },
        'requestError':function(rejection)
        {
            $q.reject(rejection);
        },
        'response':function(response){
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        'responseError':function(response)
        {
            if(response!=null && response.status == 401)
            {
                delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
                //make the user login again
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);   
        }       
    };
});
}])
```

The interceptor fails with the error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
at serverRequest (angular.js:9366)
at processQueue (angular.js:13248)
at angular.js:13264
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14466)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14282)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1455)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4203)
at doBootstrap (angular.js:1453)
at bootstrap (angular.js:1473)
```

Comment: You don't need to define all the interceptor methods if you're not actually doing anything with them. I would omit `requestError` and `response` for example.

Comment: did you try console logging the config object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return the `config` value...

```
request: function(config) {
    if ($window.sessionStorage) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
    }
    return config;
}
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

> `request`: interceptors get called with a http config object. The function is free to modify the config object or create a new one.
>   The function **needs to return** the `config` object directly, or a promise containing the `config` or a new `config` object.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use a factory and make sure, your headers object is set to an object:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('AuthInterceptor', ["$window", "$q", function ($window, $q) {

    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage) {
               config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if(response != null && response.status == 401)
            {
                delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
                //make the user login again
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    }
  }]);
```

and in your config part use:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push("AuthInterceptor");
```

Comment: OP **is** using a factory, just an unnamed / anonymous one. I think it's pretty safe to assume Angular will pass a `headers` object as part of `config`.